# Usage of rare earth barium copper oxide (ReBCo) superconductors (for fusion reactors)

Tags: superconductivity, fusion

Recently, scientist from MIT have proposed a new design for a compact fusion reactor, see for example this [ArXiV paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.3540).

I do not want to discuss the physics of their reactor but am more interested in the superconductor they propose to use: rare earth barium copper oxide (ReBCo). I am interested in the availability of these high-temperature superconductors and in the applicability using them for a large experiments, requiring in principle industry production standards.

My question: Does anybody who has insights into the field of superconductors can give a comment on the usage of ReBCos for large scale coils?